# Is it possible to configure gRPC retry options in C++?

Tags: c++, grpc

I have discovered that transparent retries are quite new to the gRPC C++ implementation, and there isn't a lot of documentation, except to say that GRPC_ARG_ENABLE_RETRIES turns the feature on and off.

Other programming languages have options: MaxAttempts, InitialBackoff, MaxBackoff, BackoffMultiplier & RetryableStatusCodes, but I can't find any reference to those for C++.

Do you know how to access these options in C++, or are they inaccessible?

Answer (score 2):

These options can be set via the [gRPC service config](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/service_config.md).  For details, see [gRFC A6](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/A6-client-retries.md).

Note that in gRPC C++, the configurable retry functionality was deemed stable and enabled by default (i.e., the `GRPC_ARG_ENABLE_RETRIES` channel arg defaults to true) in v1.40.  Transparent retries were implemented in v1.45.  Hedging has not yet been implemented, but we do plan to do that at some point in the future.